# password_verify for hashed password

Tags: php

I have admin page that will insert user id, password, role. The password will be hash after admin insert new user. It work well but when I try to login using the hash password, it will pop up "invalid user or password". Maybe because I put the password_verify coding in the wrong place. Can someone help me!!

Below is my coding

login.php

```
<?php
session_start(); // Starting Session
$error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
$error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}
else
{
// Define $username and $password
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","company");
// To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $username);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $password);

// SQL query to fetch information of registerd users and finds user match.
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "select * from login where password='$password' AND username='$username'");
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($rows == 1) {
$pwdCheck = password_verify($password,$row['password']); $_SESSION['user']=array(
   'username'=>$row['username'],
   'password'=>$row['password'],
   'role'=>$row['role']
   );
   $role=$_SESSION['user']['role'];
   //Redirecting User Based on Role
    switch($role){

 case 'user':
if ($pwdCheck == true)          
  header("location: index.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
  break;

  case 'admin':
if ($pwdCheck == true)          
  header("location: adminindex.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
  break;

 }
}
else {
$error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}   
mysqli_close($connection); // Closing Connection
}
}
?>
```

crud_include.php (admin insert new user)

```
if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $role = $_POST['role'];

        $hashedPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO login (username, password,role) VALUES ('$username', '$hashedPwd','$role')"); 
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Successfully saved!"; 
        header('location: crud.php');
    }
```

the database (the hash work well but i cannot login using this user

[image]

Comment: in the select query, you cant match on password, you just match on user-name, then check the password

Comment: Take out `password='$password'`. Also remove the `stripslashes` and you'd be better of with parameterized queries.

Comment: I plan to change from mysqli non prepare to mysqli with prepare statement but it confusing to change all the coding. Btw, the login work when I take out password='$password'. :)

Comment: Because the hashed version doesn't equal the plain text version. Yes, prepared will be much better.

Comment: erm but the when I take out password='$password'. The user can login freely. How???

Comment: @Wan1234 Not really. First, check the username. If you found one, get its corresponding password, then use it in `password_verify`

Comment: @Swellar I want to redirect user based on user role. That's make me confuse how to put the verify password. Which is admin will redirect to adminindex, while user will go to index.

Comment: I don't see the connection between the password and the roles of the users. `password_verify` will just verify the user password versus the hashed password in the database, regardless of the roles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your select query : In a where case use only username

```
<?php 
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "select * from login WHERE username='$username'");
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($rows == 1) {
    if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
        echo 'Password is valid!';
        if($role=$_SESSION['user']['role'] == 'user'){
             header("location: index.php");
        }elseif($role=$_SESSION['user']['role'] == 'admin'){
            header("location: adminindex.php");
        }
    } else {
        $error = "Password is invalid";
    }
}else{
    $error = "Username is invalid";
}
?>
```

Hope it will help you.
[Here the the link for the hash password verified](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: I want to redirect user based on user role. That's make me confuse how to put the verify password. I still not find the solution.

Comment: In valid password section put if condition If($role=$_SESSION['user']['role'] == 'user'){header("location: index.php");}elseif($role=$_SESSION['user']['role'] == 'admin'){header("location: adminindex.php");}

Comment: It would be better you used prepared statements instead

Comment: It's not working..I cannot login. It's show "Username is Invalid". I insert the password "1234" in the admin page. Then, in the login page also I put "1234". Still it doesn't work..hmm

Comment: "Username is Invalid" mean you typing a wrong username according to the condition.